# Http message content as a stream

Tags: java, netty, httplistener

I'm developing a simple HTTP listener using Netty and would like to get the HTTP content as a stream. Is there a implementation of `InputStream` by Netty which provides this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: 'HTTP listener' to what? `java.net.HttpURLConnection` *has* a `getInputStream()` method, if that's what you're referring to, but evidently it isn't.

Comment: Actually I'm developing the Http server with the Netty framework. There we get the buffers for chunks. I want to create a input stream from these chunks. I'm wondering weather netty provides a standard input stream for doing this. Sorry for the confusion if the question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received the whole HttpMessage its possible to wrap and ChannelBufferInputStream around the ChannelBuffer that you can obtain via HttpMessage.getContent(). Be aware that this will hold the whole http message in memory so it may take some memory. So caution here..

You may also need to place HttpChunkAggregator in your ChannelPipeline so you don't need to handle HttpChunk's by your self.

See:

http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpChunkAggregator.html

Comment: Thanks Norman, but this isn't very memory efficient. Is it possible to read the HttpContent objects progressively while consuming them on the fly via an Inputstream?